# How to build sqlite for Python 2.4?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I would like to use pysqlite interface between Python and sdlite database. I have already Python and SQLite on my computer. But I have troubles with installation of pysqlite. During the installation I get the following error message:

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

As far as I understood the problems appears because version of my Python is 2.4.3 and SQLite is integrated in Python since 2.5. However, I also found out that it IS possible to build sqlite for Python 2.4 (using some tricks, probably).

Does anybody know how to build sqlite for Python 2.4?

As another option I could try to install higher version of Python. However I do not have root privileges. Does anybody know what will be the easiest way to solve the problem (build SQLite fro Python 2.4, or install newer version of Python)? I have to mention that I would not like to overwrite the old version version of Python.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: pysqlite works fine with 2.4. Paste the error message(s), not message indicating there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install Python to your home directory.

```
$ cd
$ mkdir opt
$ mkdir downloads
$ cd downloads
$ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/Python-2.6.2.tgz
$ tar xvzf Python-2.6.2.tgz
$ cd Python-2.6.2
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/ --enable-unicode=ucs4
$ make
$ make install
```

Then, (if you are using bash) in your .bash_profile do

```
export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/opt/lib:$HOME/opt/lib/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Then, source the file to make it available

```
$ cd
$ source .bash_profile
$ python -V
```

where python -V will return the python version.  If the correct version appears, any packages that you run with Python's setup.py util (assuming the developer followed the correct conventions) will install in ~/opt/lib/python2.x/site-packages directory.

Answer (score 1):

Download pysqlite [here](http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/download/pysqlite/2.5/2.5.5/pysqlite-2.5.5.tar.gz), cd into the directory you downloaded to, unpack the tarball:

```
$ tar xzf pysqlite-2.5.5.tar.gz
```

then just do (if your permissions are set right for this; may need `sudo` otherwise):

```
$ cd pysqlite-2.5.5
$ python2.4 setup.py install
```

one error does appear in the copious output:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pysqlite2/test/py25tests.py", line 48
    with self.con:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

since as clearly shown that file is for py 2.5 tests only (`with` statement not present in 2.4!-).  Nevertheless the install is successful:

```
$ python2.4 -c'import pysqlite2'
$
```

All this is on Mac OS X 10.5 but using python2.4 separately installed from the system-supplied Python 2.5.

The error you report doesn't tell us much -- maybe you're missing the headers or libraries for sqlite itself?  Can you show us other output lines around that single error msg...?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root privileges, I would recommend installing a more recent version of Python in your home directory and then adding your local version to your `PATH`. It seems easier to go that direction than to try to make sqlite work with an old version of Python.

You will also be doing yourself a favor by using a recent version of Python, because you'll have access to the numerous recent improvements in the language.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with gcc failing with Ubuntu Karmic. I fixed this by installing the python-dev package. In my case, I'm working with python2.4, so I installed the python2.4-dev package. The python-dev package should work for python2.6.